# Weak law of large numbers for dampened Cauchy distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Say I have a sequence of real independent functions $X_i$ on a probability space $(\Omega, P)$ such that $(X_i)_* P$ gives the probability distribution $d\alpha := \frac{cdx}{(1+x^2)\log(1+x^2)}$ (say for $|x| > 1$) where $c$ is a normalizing constant.

I want to solve an exercise which asks to show $\frac{S_n}{n} := \frac{X_1 + \dots + X_n}{n}$ converges in probability to a constant function. Or equivalently that the characteristic function of $\left(\frac{S_n}{n}\right)_*P$ converges to that of a probability supported on a point.

This boils down to checking the differentiability at $0$ of the characteristic function $\phi$ of $d\alpha$ which I'm having trouble with (Note, the function $x$ is not integrable with respect to $d\alpha$). I have

$$\frac{\phi(s) - 1}{s} = \frac{c}{s}\int\limits_{|x| > 1} \frac{e^{isx} - 1}{(1+x^2)\log(1+x^2)}dx
$$

and the exercise would follow if I showed the limit as $s\to 0$ existed since the characteristic function of $\left(\frac{S_n}{n}\right)_*P$ is $\phi(\frac{\cdot}{n})^n$.

Can someone please help me evaluate this limit? Normally, pushing the limit inside the integral works but in this case it definitely will not :(

**Edit:** The original distribution was modified to have support away from $0$.

Comment: Surely no such distribution exists because $\int_0^\epsilon\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)\ln(1+x^2)}\sim\int_0^\epsilon\frac{dx}{x^2}=\infty$ for small $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: I see. I'm guessing here, but maybe the exercise wants us to assume that this density is supported away from a neighbourhood of $0$? Can anything be done in this case? For reference, this is Exercise 3.6 in Varadhan's book. I hope I've read correctly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to the book: W. Feller, *An Introduction to Probability and Its Applications*(2nd Ed.,1971),  Th.VII.7.1, p235 and Th.XVII.2a, p565. In these theorems, the necessary and sufficient conditions of LLN for i.i.d.r.v's are given in terms of distribution function(also characteristic function).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please explain how the differentiation of the characteristic function argument goes? I understand the truncation argument.